# Given $u = \frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2}$ and $v = \frac{-2y}{x^2 + y^2}$, write $x$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I have these two equations

$$u = \frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2} \\
v = \frac{-2y}{x^2 + y^2}$$

And I need to write $x$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. If I take polar coordinates and plug them in, I get (in the case of $u$): because $(r \cos \theta )^2 + (r \sin \theta )^2 = 1$,$$u = 2r\cos \theta .$$

Can I simply change that back to$$u = 2x ?$$

Comment: By the sound of it, you think that $x^2-y^2=1$ after plugging in $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. This is false.

Comment: whoops- sorry - I mistyped

Comment: Can you show your working for $u=2r\cos\theta$?

Comment: Unfortunately, $r^2 \cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta = r^2$, not 1. So you should get $u=2r^{-1}\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$. Then
$$
u = \frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{2 \cos \theta}{r}
$$
$$
v = \frac{-2y}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{- 2 \sin \theta}{r}
$$
Dividing these gives
$$
\tan \theta = - \frac{v}{u} \Rightarrow \theta = \tan^{-1} \left(-\frac{v}{u}\right),
$$
and squaring and then adding gives
$$
u^2 + v^2 = \frac{4}{r^2} \Rightarrow r = \frac{2}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}.
$$
You now have $r$ and $\theta$, and thus $x$ and $y$, in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: wait up, isn't your v/u the other way around if it's to equal tan?

Comment: @scuba: No, why?

Answer (score 2):

In polar/Cartesian coordinates, using standard variables, $x^2+y^2 = r^2$, so your first equation could be written $$u=\frac{2x}{r^2}$$ But then also, $x=r\cos\theta$, so $$u=\frac{2\cos(\theta)}{r}$$
So there is your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using polar coordinates:

$$u=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\longrightarrow\frac{2r\cos\theta}{r^2}=\frac{2\cos\theta}{r}$$

$$v=-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\longrightarrow -\frac{2r\sin\theta}{r^2}=-\frac{2\sin\theta}{r}$$

which is different from what you wrote...

Comment: mhmm ok, so after I get that, how do I put x in terms of u and v?